# Problem with starting TeamViewer 10 on Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: teamviewer

I have installed TeamViewer 10 successfully.

When I'm trying to run it :

```
$ teamviewer
```

Gets me following error :

> /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/tvw_exec: line 8:
>
> /home/ismail/.config/teamviewer10/logfiles/startup.log: Permission
>   denied flock: 300: Bad file descriptor

P.S :

Teamviewer daemon is already running :

```
$ sudo teamviewer --daemon start
```

Ouput :

> initctl start teamviewerd initctl: Job is already running: teamviewerd
>   fail

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because the /home/$USER/.config/teamviewer directory was owned by root from the installation. I ran

> sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.config/teamviewer

to fix this problem.